Finding the volume of a revolution for an asymmetric function
keyless alto saxophone
context: I'm an HL IB Applications and Interpretations Math student and for my Internal Assessment I was planning on graphing an object and taking the volume of a revolution for it. However, basically everyone in my class is doing a vase, so i chose my saxophone.
Is it possible to take the volume of a revolution for a saxophone? Even if you divide it up into sections, the bell (curved out section) is not symmetrical but rather has almost parallel lines. Can I take half the volume of a revolution for each side and add them together? Or would this be incorrect? I saw someone post a similar question in the past, but it didn't really receive a clear answer. Also, would I need to use the washer method for this? I wasn't sure because it is basically the same outside and inside radius since the metal is just a thin circle.
If this is not possible, I am thinking about switching my object to a soprano saxophone which would probably be more easy to graph since it doesn't have as many curves. If anyone has any suggestions or information, I would greatly appreciate it. thanks in advance

The problem with using the saxophone for this task is that it lacks a uniform axis of symmetry - it's not a straight line like that of a right cylinder or cone, rather an S-shaped two dimensional curve i.e. the path that air takes as it's blown into the instrument. Are you familiar at all with line integrals?

@user170231 but line integrals aren’t used with volume of revolution, are they? Also, that’s why I was wondering if it was possible to chunk the saxophone into different sections creating multiple axes so the sax is divided in halves while each half is rotated to create a whole.
